# how to install a c#.net com dll with cab file

Tags: .net, cab, activexobject, dllregistration

how to install a c#.net com dll with cab file.

I am having a .net com dll(active x) , how to install this by using cab files.

Comment: You've asked variations of the same 'question' four times now.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://www.mrrives.com/Technology/?p=767

3 seconds of google search by the way...